# Android: change xml elements after server call

Tags: android, xml, dynamic

I was wondering if there was a program I could include into my app that would let me change the layout of certain `XML` elements such as color, width, height, etc after a call from our server.

We want to accomplish semi-dynamic layout changes without having the user update the app from the Play Store.

Anyone know of any existing programs that do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't suppose you can change xml elements at runtime. But you can retrieve the specifications from the server and change the layout programmatically

Comment: I was thinking the doing the same thing, but was wondering if there was a program that let me do this in a simplified way. Kind of like `LeanPlum`.

Comment: A program, I don't know. But normally there is no way to change xml elements at runtime. BUT, if you do  get a program please post it as an answer. Even I would be benefited by such a program :)